# pandas.to_html() for elements in a list show new line characters

Tags: html, pandas

I have a bunch of pandas dataframes in a list that I need to convert to html tables.  The html code for each individual dataframe looks good, however when I append the html to a list I end up with a bunch of `\n` characters showing on my webpage.  Can anyone tell me how to get rid of them?

**python code**:

```
dataframe_html = []
table_dic = {}

for df in dataframes:
  frame = df.to_html(classes="table table-hover")
  dataframe_html.append(frame)  #this is the line where all the \n get added

table_dic.update({'dataframe_html':dataframe_html})

return render(request,'InterfaceApp/FileProcessor_results.html',table_dic)
```

**html code**:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    {{ dataframe_html | safe }}
</div>
```

Shows up like this:

[image]'

Can anyone help me out with this??

Comment: Change that to: dataframe_html.append(frame.strip())

Comment: @tanjir I tried `dataframe_html.append(frame.strip('\n'))` and the `\n` are still there.

Comment: What about dataframe_html.append(frame.strip('u\n')) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display 3 separate tables, join the list of HTML strings into a single string:

```
dataframe_html = u''.join(dataframe_html)
```

---

```
for df in dataframes:
    frame = df.to_html(classes="table table-hover")
    dataframe_html.append(frame)  
dataframe_html = u''.join(dataframe_html)
table_dic = {'dataframe_html':dataframe_html}

return render(request,'InterfaceApp/FileProcessor_results.html',table_dic)
```

Comment: I need them to be separate tables though.  Your solution produces one table.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this late in the game:

I had originally had:

```
    response = render_template('table_display.html', query_results=[df_html], query_name='Quality Item Query')
```

and was getting an entire row of \n characters.  Changed to below and the newlines disappeared.

```
    response = render_template('table_display.html', query_results=df_html, query_name='Quality Item Query')
```

Answer (score 1):

Even later in the game...

I stumbled upon this thread when having the same problem.  Hopefully, the below helps someone.

I assigned the results of `df.to_html()` to a (nested) list and got the new lines when rendering in my Jinja template.  The solution inspired by **@AlliDeacon** was to index the result again when rendering

Python code:

```
result[0][0] = df.to_html()
```

Jinja template:

```
<div>Table: {{ result[0][0][0] }}</div>
```

Refer output of the following code for illustration of the difference between a (sub-)list and a list element:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b']],
              columns=['col_A', 'col_B'])

tmp = []
tmp.append(df.to_html(index=False))

print(tmp)

print(tmp[0])
```

Result:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>col_A</th>
      <th>col_B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tgf, why the edit?  It is not duplicate html, that is the whole point of the post.  One version will render correctly, the other version will add \n s in the resulting page.  With the edit the post is losing its point.

Answer (score 0):

Even more than late than late to the game. The issue with the newline characters is that the frame is by default in JSON when passed from your app to Jinja. The \n's are being read literally, but the table gets constructed from what follows inside the JSON string. There are two cases to deal with this, depending on the method of passing your dataframe:

**Case 1: Passing a dataframe with render_template:**

Pass the frame in your app without the "df.to_html". Within your html use the Jinja2 syntax to obtain a clean frame without any newline characters:

```
{{ df_html.to_html(classes="your-fancy-table-class") | safe }}
```

**Case 2: Passing with json.dumps to be retrieved in JS**

In case you send your frame via a response, e.g. post Ajax request, pass the frame with df.to_html() as you did:

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) #load and return the frame route
def foo():
   # df = pd.DataFrame...
   return json.dumps({"response": df.to_html}
```

Then in your JS, load the clean frame without the newline characters in HTML from your response with:

```
JSON.parse(data).response;
$("#your-table-wrapper").html(response);
```